# Opensource software for AMD A10 monitoring

Tags: linux, cpu, gpu, amd-radeon

I have an ASUS X550Z laptop which has an AMD A10 7400P processor. This processor says it has 10 [compute cores](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/processors-for-business/compute-cores) in description. I am not quite sure I understand the technology completely, but it seems to me that all 10 cores should behave identically. I don't know much about CPU and GPU hardware other than the basics so please correct me if I am wrong about this.

tl;dr - Is there any opensource software out there that can give me performance monitoring of all 10 cores (or 4 CPU cores + GPU performance)? I'd like to hear about licensed software too, but really need it to be opensource since I work on Linux.

Details:
If, as per the link, all 10 cores can truly share all the tasks, I should be able to see some performance from the GPU cores as well. Even if I don't see all 10 cores, I should see some activity on a GPU monitoring system.
I have Linux Mint installed on the machine and the system monitoring tool in there only shows 4 CPU cores. I also installed `radeontop` but that is just showing 0 for everything, so I suspect that is not right tool, or the version I have is not working with the A10. `lspci` does show the `radeon` driver in use but I'm not sure how much is being used. I also have LFS built on another partition of the laptop, and the xfce system monitor also only shows 4 cores.
What I want to figure out is that are all the 10 cores really being used as advertised? If no such software exists, is there some other way for me to know that the processor indeed works as advertised, and that the GPU cores are helping out with the tasks? Feel free to suggest expert mode options for Linux. Also, this is purely out of curiosity so useful links will be much appreciated even if they can't solve the problem.

Comment: Okay...so I installed a newer version of `radeontop` and I see some usage now, but still would like to know see the usage of each core just to see if the GPU cores are helping out with non-graphics processes as well

Comment: As per the rules of this site: `Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question`